# How to update an unsigned record safely against negative value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a trigger like this which keeps the total value in the parent table:

```
UPDATE posts p SET total_comments = GREATEST(total_comments - 1, 0) WHERE old.post_id = p.id
```

I've used `GREATEST()` to avoid negative numbers, but still, I get this error if the current value of `total_comments`  is `0` and then the trigger executes:

> #1690 - BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in (mydb.p.total_comments - 1)

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Out-of-Range and Overflow Handling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html):

> Subtraction between integer values, where one is of type UNSIGNED,
> produces an unsigned result by default. If the result would otherwise
> have been negative, an error results

In your case `total_comments` is defined as `UNSIGNED` and if its value is `0` then the evaluation of the expression `total_comments - 1` throws an error.

A workaround would be to compare `total_comments` to 1 inside `GREATEST()` and after that do the subtraction:

```
UPDATE posts p 
SET total_comments = GREATEST(total_comments, 1) - 1 
WHERE old.post_id = p.id
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using `where` clause to avoid updating it if it's already `0`. Try this:

```
UPDATE posts p
SET total_comments = total_comments - 1
WHERE old.post_id = p.id
  AND total_comments > 0
```